# Getting Null pointer Exception while using the Java mail api to send mail from local host using gmail smtp.

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

In servlet class i am initializing all the variable in init method

```
private String host="smtp.gmail.com";
private String port="465";
private String user="abc@gmail.com";
private String pass="pass";
public void init()
{
    // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    host = context.getInitParameter("host");
    port = context.getInitParameter("port");
    user = context.getInitParameter("user");
    pass = context.getInitParameter("pass");
}
```

In EmailUtility class i am having the code below

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");


    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() 
    {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);


    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText(message);   
    Transport.send(msg);
```

Stack Trace of Exception is

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
    at EmailUtility.sendEmail(EmailUtility.java:31)
    at EmailSendingServlet.doPost(EmailSendingServlet.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I am trying to test this mail sending mechanism on my local host using gmail smtp. Unable to track why this Exception occurs. I have also tried to run this by changing the port number but ended up with the same problem.

Comment: Where specifically in this code block is this exception being thrown?

Comment: In EmailUtility class at properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`host` is coming back `null`.  Since `Properties` extends `Hashtable`, you're making use of Hashtable's `put` method.  But, [`put` will throw an NPE if either the key or value are `null`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put(K,%20V)):

> Throws:
>
> `NullPointerException` - if the key or value is null

Ensure that you're getting a value back from all invocations of `context.getInitParameter` and that they're making their way to their correct variables.